# Count Array elements in String

Tags: arrays, io, fortran

I'm trying to read a string containing an unknown number of integers into a Fortran Array.

```
string = "2  5,7 6 0"
```

Parsing the string itself works, since I know the maximal possible size of the Array. The delimiters can vary, like for example spaces, tabs comma or combination of those
But how do I count how many elements I've read?
At the moment my code looks like:

```
program count_string_elements
  implicit none
  character(len=50) :: string
  integer :: i, count, imax, ios
  integer,allocatable :: tmp_arr(:)

  imax = 20
  allocate(tmp_arr(imax))

  string = "2  5,7 6 0"
  read(unit=string, fmt=*, iostat=ios) (tmp_arr(i), i=1,imax)
  print *, tmp_arr

  deallocate(tmp_arr)
end program
```

With the output being

```
2    5    7    6    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Setting it to a default value like -1, 0, or something is not an option since I can't exclude they are in the string.

Is there a way to abort the reading such that i contains the amount of elements (or amount of elements+1)?

> Update
>   I found one way by extending the code above a bit.

```
program count_string_elements
  implicit none
  character(len=50) :: string
  integer :: i, cnt, imax, ios
  integer,allocatable :: tmp_arr(:)
  character(len=50) :: str_arr(:)
  imax = 20
  allocate(tmp_arr(imax), str_arr(imax))

  string = "2  5,7 6 0"
  cnt = 0
  read(unit=string, fmt=*, iostat=ios) (str_arr(i), i=1,imax)
  do i = 1, imax
    if(len_trim(str_arr(i)) == 50) cycle
    cnt = cnt + 1
    read(str_arr(i),*) tmp_arr(cnt)
  end do
  print *, tmp_arr(:cnt)

  deallocate(str_arr, tmp_arr)
end program
```

But there is probably a nicer way to do this.

Comment: Your read command is just one statement, not a loop, you cannot abort it in between, you have to do something more involved. The `(tmp_arr(i), i=1,imax)` is just the same as `tmp_arr(1:imax)` or in theis case as just `tmp_arr`.

Comment: You could first do lexical analysis and divide the string into a list of tokens, but for this simple integer application it will be overkill. Just go over the string in a loop and shift a window from which you are reading.

Comment: You could also use something as my function `count_multispaces` in https://bitbucket.org/LadaF/elmm/src/f10a1b3421a3dd14fdcbe165aa70bf5c5001413f/src/strings.f90?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default which I don't really use any more, but does almost what you want. Just use more separators then just a space ` ` and add 1 to the result.

Comment: It works for multidigit integers as well as negative integer just fine. The cycle would screw things only up if there was a 50 digit integer, that won't happen.

Comment: OK, I can see now what you did. A bit wasteful on memory, but will work.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different possible integer values. It shouldn't be too hard, depending on the type of data you have to find one that is unlikely to be part of a data set, and use that one as a dummy.

That said, the way I would solve that (quick and dirty) is to just go through the whole string and count the number of transitions between non-digits and digits.

See this example:

```
program arb_array

    implicit none
    character(len=30) :: test_string
    integer :: imax
    integer :: array(10)

    test_string = "2  5,7 6 0"

    imax = count_integers(test_string)

    read(test_string, *) array(:imax)
    print*, imax, array(:imax)

contains

    function is_digit(c)
        implicit none
        character, intent(in) :: c
        logical :: is_digit
        is_digit = ((ichar(c) >= ichar('0')) .and. (ichar(c) <= ichar('9')))
        return
    end function is_digit

    function count_integers(string) result(imax)
        implicit none
        character(len=*), intent(in) :: string
        integer :: imax
        integer :: i

        imax=0
        i = 1
        counter_loop : do
            do while (.not. is_digit(string(i:i)))
                i = i + 1
                if (i > len(string)) exit counter_loop
            end do
            imax = imax+1
            do while (is_digit(string(i:i)))
                i = i + 1
                if (i > len(string)) exit counter_loop
            end do
        end do counter_loop

    end function count_integers
end program arb_array
```